# Woocommerce Disabling Auto Restocking for Cancelled Orders

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

When we cancel an order, Woocommerce automatically restocking the products. But we do not want auto restocking so I've tried this hook:

```
function filter_woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock( $true, $order ) {
        $stat  = $order->get_status();
        if($stat == 'cancelled'){ // We want only disable restocking when status is cancelled.
            $note = 'order stat is '.$stat.' so we do NOT updated the item stock.';
            $order->add_order_note( $note ); // To be make sure what happened.
            return false; // Do not restock the product.
        }else{
            $note = 'order stat is '.$stat.' so we UPDATED the item stock.';
            $order->add_order_note( $note );
            return true; // Restock the product.
        }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock','filter_woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock', 10, 2 );
```

Also tried this hook too:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_can_restore_order_stock', 'ts_do_not_restock', 10, 2 );
function ts_do_not_restock( $true, $order ){
    $stat  = $order->get_status();
    if($stat == 'cancelled'){
        $note = 'order stat is '.$stat.' so we do not updated the item stock.';
        $order->add_order_note( $note ); // To be make sure what happened.
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

But both not worked for me, any ideas to disabling auto restocking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received my answer from Woocommerce support. It's working like a charm:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_stop_cancelled_restock', 0 );
function my_stop_cancelled_restock() {
    remove_action('woocommerce_order_status_cancelled', 'wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels');    
}
```